# Hiding a chart series in python-pptx

Tags: python-pptx

Using `python-pptx`, how can I create a new chart populated with multiple series of data but only show some of those series visibly on the chart? The other series should be in the background data of the chart but not visible when the slide is presented (see image 1 for clarification).

[Image 1: Selection of columns that are to be shown initially](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYa5p.jpg)

The intention is that I have multiple types of measurements (percentage, absolute, index) for the same slide. At first I only want to show the percentage values on the chart. If the chart does not look nice, I want to be able to rightclick on the chart and select other columns with other measurements to be shown (see image 2).

[Image 2: Newly selected columns that were previously hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HclIp.jpg)

A workaround would be to create hidden slides for each additional measurement and then to activate them if needed. But that does not work for my case - the data must be all in one slide like in the examples.

Looking forward to reading your answers! :)

current test code:

```
prs = Presentation("MyPPTX.pptx")
chart_layout = prs.slide_layouts[11]
chart_placeholder = prs.slides.add_slide(chart_layout).placeholders[15]

# define chart data ---------------------
chart_data_prz = ChartData()
chart_data_prz.categories = ['Male', 'Female']
chart_data_prz.add_series('Age_18-34_in_%', (51,49))
chart_data_prz.add_series('Video-Streaming_in_%', (58, 42))
chart_data_prz.add_series('Age_18-34_in_Mio', (105, 96))
chart_data_prz.add_series('Video-Streaming_in_Mio', (118, 83))
prz_chart = chart_placeholder.insert_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED,chart_data_prz)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API support for this in the current version of `python-pptx` (v0.6.17).

The embedded Excel workbook providing the chart data is derived from the same `ChartData` object the chart is; that is, the only way to get data into the chart's Excel workbook with `python-pptx` is to put it in the `ChartData` object used to create the chart, and `python-pptx` adds all those series to the chart (which makes them visible).

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast reply! Then I will have to find another solution for my problem :)

Comment: Since I see you're new to StackOverflow I'll mention; don't neglect to accept the answer if it answers your question. This is how respondents are acknowledged for taking the time to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
from pptx.oxml.xmlchemy import OxmlElement

def SubElement(parent, tagname, **kwargs):
        element = OxmlElement(tagname)
        element.attrib.update(kwargs)
        parent.append(element)
        return element

def hideSeriesAndRemoveFromLegend(chart,
                                  seriesIndex):
    """Data labels (if they exist) are not hidden"""
    ## Set series to no fill
    chart.chart.series[seriesIndex].format._element.get_or_add_spPr().get_or_change_to_noFill()
    ## # Remove entry from legend
    ## Get legend
    legend = chart.chart.legend._element
    ## Add legendEntry
    lE = SubElement(legend, "c:legendEntry")
    ## Add idx of the series, index order is reversed
    seriesCount = len(chart.chart.series)
    seriesIndexToDelete = seriesCount - 1 - seriesIndex
    _ = SubElement(lE, "c:idx", val=str(seriesIndexToDelete))
    ## Add delete 
    _ = SubElement(lE, "c:delete", val="1")
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but it appears as though this is editing the visibility of the data in the chart, rather than the data selections, correct? So if the Workbook were opened up, it would still show the original data selection?